# Open Modalbox with generated Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a Table with data out of a JSON and add to this table with a Javascript-function buttons.

Now i want to open with this button `generated Modalboxes` with diffrent Outputs ( e.g `Hello world1` by button 1, `hello world2` by button 2).

Is there a way to solve this ?

**My Code:**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

    //JSON for table    
    var hotspots = "[{\"path\": \"src/main/java/tools/generator/data/RecordPart.java\",\"revisions\": 25,\"codeLines\": 18,\"authors\": [{\"name\": \"User1\",\"commits\": 7}]},{\"path\": \"src/main/java/tools/generator/data/RecordTotal.java\", \"revisions\": 55,\"codeLines\": 23,\"authors\": [{\"name\": \"User1\",\"commits\": 5}]},{\"path\": \"src/main/resources/test.xml\",\"revisions\": 102,\"codeLines\": 44,\"authors\": [{\"name\": \"User1\",\"commits\": 7}]},{\"path\": \"src/main/java/tools/generator/helper/MenuHelper.java\",\"revisions\": 4,\"codeLines\": 115,\"authors\": [{\"name\": \"User1\",\"commits\": 2}]}]";  
          
        var jsonHotspots = JSON.parse(hotspots);
        constructTable(jsonHotspots);
    });


    // Table out of json
    function constructTable(json) {
        var tbl=$("<table/>").attr("id","mytable");
        $("#div1").append(tbl);
        var tr="<tr>";
        var td1='<td onclick="sortTable(0)" >Path</td>';
        var td2='<td onclick="sortTable(1)" >Rev</td>';
        var td3='<td onclick="sortTable(2)" >Lines</td>';
        var td4='<td ></td></tr>';
        $("#mytable").append(tr+td1+td2+td3+td4);
        for(var i=0;i < json.length ; i++)
        {
            var tr="<tr>";
            var td1="<td>"+json[i]["path"]+"</td>";
            var td2="<td>"+json[i]["revisions"]+"</td>";
            var td3="<td>"+json[i]["codeLines"]+"</td>";
            var td4='<td><button class="button" id="myBtn'+ i +'">Show<td></tr>';
           $("#mytable").append(tr+td1+td2+td3+td4);
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="mytable"></table>
```

Comment: You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll

Comment: Kinda confused you could add a onclick to the button pass a parameter and that could do whatever you wanted. This also is a great example with opening a Modal with a parameter (or multiple). http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target

Comment: Don't use the same ID for all buttons, they must be unique or better still, use a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [element.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)

on the new buttons.

https://jsfiddle.net/zrdj703e/1/

```
document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    alert('clicked');
}
```

EDIT:
I saw now that you use jquery, then you can just use:

```
$('body').on('click','#mytable button',function({
   alert('button clicked with id: '+$(this).attr('id'));
});
```